# How much was Equilibrium influenced by Fahrenheit 451?

Tags: inspiration, dystopia, equilibrium, fahrenheit-451

I see some similarities between the movie Equilibrium and the book Fahrenheit 451. Does anyone know if there is *actually* any association? or am i just looking at the extremely basic ideas of censorship and rebellion of government employees as the basis of my observation?

Comment: The movie is even more similar to the novel [We](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_(novel)#section_5) , which infuences most modern distopian novels including 1984.

Answer (score 19):

From the DVD commentary, director Kurt Wimmer:

> You know, there's a number of films *Fahrenheit 451, Logan's Run, Gattaca, Brave New World, 1984, THX-1138, The Matrix, Alphaville, A Clockwork Orange, Handmaiden's [sic] Tale, Judge Dredd,* even *Triumph of the Will*--- all of these were films that I was accused of unapologetically ripping off to make this film.  And, you know, it's true.  I like all of these stories and I actually like some of those films and certainly I did draw inspiration from them for making my own dystopic universe.  Although I certainly wasn't trying to pull the wool over anybody's eyes.  Because at the end of the day I believe that this film is actually about something different than those films were about.  You know, I always thought that *1984* was about socialism and *Fahrenheit 451* was about McCarthyism, while for me this particular film was about numbness. [...] And also not only that but a sort of sister theme, a dangerous idea I see growing daily around me, that some people's feelings are dangerous and need to be censored.

So *Equilibrium* takes the censorship idea in a different direction; the purpose of the state's censorship is the suppression of feelings and the targets of censorship are all the arts.

Comment: That's just it. Fahrenheit 451 is the one, as far as i can tell that is the most like the movie. The censorship goes as far as destroying unwanted media, the Clerics are the Firemen, The only *real* difference is the ending. In one the character is in the perfect position to place himself as the new leader, and in the other the main character gets away from the city just in time to see the after effects of a nuclear bomb in the city he left only hours before